# Proof verification: show that $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{e^{x-1}}$ does not exist.

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

> Show that the following limit does not exist:
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{e^{x-1}}
> $$

---

Here is my attempt. Am I doing it correctly?

$$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{1}{e^{x-1}} = + \infty,\quad\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{1}{e^{x-1}} = - \infty$$

Therefore $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{e^{x-1}}$ does not exist.

Comment: Pay attention $e^y\to e^0=1$ for $y\to0$

Comment: $\lim_\limits{x\to 1}\frac {1}{e^{x -1}}$ or $\lim_\limits{x\to 1}\frac {1}{e^x -1}$?

Comment: Excercise states as I wrote it... And the instruction says to prove that limit does NOT exist..

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^{2}-1}{x^{2}+2x+1}$$   So I guess that this one does also exist and equals 0, right?

Comment: yes of course you can simply let x=1 also in this case

Comment: @Genoe Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{e^{x-1}}=\frac1{e^0}=1 $$

Comment: I suspect the limit was supposed to be $\lim_\limits{x\to 1}\frac {1}{e^x - 1}$ but that was lost in one of the edits.

Comment: Maybe you are right!

Comment: The limit would also exist, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Genoe yes of course it is 1

Answer (score 2):

There is no singularity, just plug in: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\dfrac{1}{e^{x-1}}=\dfrac{1}{e^{1-1}}=\dfrac{1}{e^{0}}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The limit exists and its value is 1. Probably a misprint.